# Bootstrap Clean Blog Template to React Application Integration Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-hooks

I am not able to properly integrate **Bootstrap Clean Blog Template** [(Link Attached)](https://startbootstrap.com/theme/clean-blog) into my React App. Its a free template as mentioned.

I downloaded the template, created a react project, copied all static assets & files to public Folder of my react Application.

The folder structure is as seen here:

[image: Folder Structure]

In my root html file i.e ***public/index.html*** I copied the header links & script tags as present in the bootstrap template home page:

**public/index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Balaji Blog App</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Google fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  
  <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Core theme JS-->
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have created three react components: Navbar, Footer, Home & have added to my App.js as shown below. The code for the same is copied from home page of bootstrap template & modified as per react:

**Navbar Component:**

```
import React from 'react';

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
            <div className="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Bajji Blog</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/post/new">New post</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/auth/register">New User</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

**Footer Component:**

```
import React from 'react';

function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer className="border-top">
            <div className="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div className="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <ul className="list-inline text-center">
                            <li className="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span className="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i className="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span className="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i className="fab fa-facebook-f fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span className="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i className="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="small text-center text-muted fst-italic">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2022</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    )
}

export default Footer;
```

**Home Component:**

```
import React from 'react';

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* Page Header*/}
            <header className="masthead" style="background-image: url('assets/img/home-bg.jpg')">
                <div className="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
                    <div className="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                        <div className="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                            <div className="site-heading">
                                <h1>Balaji Bajji Blog</h1>
                                <span className="subheading">Create Blogs of your Favorite Food</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            {/* Main Content*/}
            <div className="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div className="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">

                        {/* Post preview*/}

                        {/* Divider*/}
                        <hr className="my-4" />

                        {/* Pager*/}
                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4"><a className="btn btn-primary text-uppercase"
                            href="#!">Older Posts →</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

**Primary Component of React App.js:**

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home.js';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.js';
import Footer from './components/Footer.js';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Home />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now when I start my Application & go to home page i.e: ***localhost/3000/***, i am getting a blank screen with the following error (Error Image attached below). As per the error the script is not able to access the height of the page & so on.

[image: Error on Browser Console]

Can anyone help me properly integrate this page page of bootstrap template (link attached above) to integrate with react? I am struck since two days & not able to crack the solution.

Comment: You can give your GitHub link. Otherwise it's very hard to debug.

Comment: @ EMRAN HOSSAIN
Ok, will share the link soon. Thank you!
Also please check is there an error with my inline style element in my Home.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues overall was noticed.

Issue 1 solution: The Script Tag rather than linking on public/index.html, copy & paste the javascript contents inside HTML page.

Issue 2 Solution: The inline style attribute values should be provided as JSON object for the bable & webpack to stich properly working code...!